# oledbexeception was unhandled Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: vb.net

hi i'm having a problem on acscmd.executenonquery()

can you please give me a solution for this

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim fsreader As New FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

    Dim breader As New BinaryReader(fsreader)
    Dim imgbuffer(fsreader.length) As Byte
    breader.Read(imgbuffer, 0, fsreader.length)
    fsreader.Close()

    strsql = "insert into tablepict (name,picture) values (@dtaname, @dtapic)"

    acscmd.CommandText = strsql
    acscmd.Connection = acsconn
    acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtaname", TextBox1.Text)
    acscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtapic", imgbuffer)
    acscmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    acscmd.Dispose()
    MsgBox("saved")
End Sub
```

Comment: What are the data types of your `name` and `picture` columns?  The error message suggests that at least one of them is not compatible with the data types of the data you're providing.

Comment: sorry for late reply , i already fix the problem :)
thanks for the comment :)